# Convert mpi_allgather to mpi_allgatherv

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran

I have an original version of code in F90, where it was trying to use mpi_allgather to gather vectors of the same length in each CPU. However, I am modifying the code which leads to the length of the vector in each CPU being different. So I'm trying to modify mpi_allgather to mpi_allgatherv. However, it shows a segmentation fault if I tried simply changing the function.

```
nnodes = size(nodes)
nnodes_all = 0
call mpi_allreduce(nnodes, nnodes_all, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, mpi_comm_world, ierr)

allocate(nxyz1(nnodes*ndim))
allocate(nxyz_gather1(nnodes_all*ndim))
allocate(nxyz2(nnodes_all, ndim))
nxyz1 = zero; nxyz_gather1 = zero; nxyz2 = zero

ct = 1
do i = 1, size(nodes)
   do j = 1, ndim
      nxyz1(ct) = nodes(i) % xyz(j)
      ct = ct + 1
   end do
end do

call mpi_allgather(nxyz1, nnodes*ndim, MPI_DOUBLE, nxyz_gather1, nnodes*ndim, MPI_DOUBLE, mpi_comm_world, ierr)
```

This is the original version which works in the case of the same vector length in each CPU.

I realized I might also need to include stride and displacement in the argument to make mpi_allgatherv works, but I'm getting lost doing so.

Comment: ẅelcome, please take the [tour]. I also suggest reading [ask] and [mcve]. You cannot just change the name of the subroutine being called. Their arguments are different. If you have some actual code that tries to call `MPI_AllgatherV` and fails, please show it. But follow at least the basic interface from the manual https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_Allgatherv.3.php You have to supply the required arrays.

Comment: Please always include a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.